# How to re-write the code for the following workflow , first upload a video and then process it?

Tags: javascript

```
   First, I'm trying to change the behavior for uploading a video and then press the button "corta" and It will cut, Any Idea, please?
    .
    The current behavior is that it will cut when you change the data of the input file ( When you upload a video ) and It's not waiting for clicking button "corta".
```

That's the link of the functionality, thanks.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.9.5/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">corta</button>
    <video id="output-video" controls></video><br />
    <input type="file" id="uploader">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {

            const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = FFmpeg;
            const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });

            const trim = async ({ target: { files } }) => {
                const message = document.getElementById('message');
                const { name } = files[0];
                message.innerHTML = 'Loading ffmpeg-core.js';
                await ffmpeg.load();
                message.innerHTML = 'Start trimming';
                ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', name, await fetchFile(files[0]));
                await ffmpeg.run('-i', name, '-ss', '0', '-to', '1', 'output.mp4');
                message.innerHTML = 'Complete trimming';
                const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.mp4');

                const video = document.getElementById('output-video');
                video.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
            }
            const elm = document.getElementById('uploader');
            elm.addEventListener('change', trim);
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are pressing a button which runs a function which does nothing. it adds an event listener. you want to call trim

Comment: Yes, but the trim method will be called when you change the input type="file" , It means it will process that method only when that input changes its data and I'm not looking for that , I need to upload the video and click the button "corta" and It will cut, I'm thinking about how to change that.

Comment: added an answer which sorts it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, your button on click `myFunction` does nothing but create a function and attach an event listener. you want
to move those out of the function.

Then you want to target the input element, and not just use the event.target since the event target will be different if someone clicks the button.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.9.5/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="corta">corta</button>
    <video id="output-video" controls></video><br />
    <input type="file" id="uploader">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <script>
        (function() {
            const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = FFmpeg;
            const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
            const input = document.getElementById('uploader');
            const corta = document.getElementById('corta');
            const trim = async () => {
                if (input.files.length > 0) {
                  const message = document.getElementById('message');
                  const { name } = input.files[0];
                  message.innerHTML = 'Loading ffmpeg-core.js';
                  await ffmpeg.load();
                  message.innerHTML = 'Start trimming';
                  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', name, await fetchFile(input.files[0]));
                  await ffmpeg.run('-i', name, '-ss', '0', '-to', '1', 'output.mp4');
                  message.innerHTML = 'Complete trimming';
                  const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.mp4');

                  const video = document.getElementById('output-video');
                  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
                }
            }
    
            corta.addEventListener('click', trim);
        })(); // Self invoking as to not create global variables.
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got this mistake,  files is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.trim  , could you help me, please. I think It is here :                 const { name } = input.files[0];   . If you are able , could you explain me more , what happens with that element ?             const input = document.getElementById('uploader');
 and why is getting an error, when you write input.files[0]

Comment: You will get that issue if you try to use the button when there is no file uploaded. you will need to check if that exists before doing any more. ill update my answer. updated. and works.